# PHP If Checkbox Checked, Then (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

**Intro**

I have some custom fields in my WordPress profile area. Here's an example of a checkbox in my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="A" id="A" value="yes" <?php if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( "A", $user->ID )) == "yes") echo "checked"; ?> /><label for="my_field "><?php _e("Order Button"); ?></label><br />
```

This field is `A`, and I'm saving it in the same file with:

```
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'A', $_POST['A'] );
```

This is working, and when the user clicks it on or off, it saves.

### The Problem

However, I am having a big issue posting the results if the checkbox was checked.

In another file I have this:

```
if(isset($_POST['A'])) {
echo 'asd';
} else { }
```

I have tried a lot of variations, but I can not figure out how to get the If statement to check whether the user checked the box or not, it only echos the `else`.

### TL;DR:

I can't figure out how to check if the usermeta is checked or not, and how to output that into another element of the website.

http://pastebin.com/Q3WSv47m Link to User Profile Code

http://pastebin.com/spU2dqGk Link to Header area where I'm trying to call the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You must check checked variable value. Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['A']) && $_POST['A'] == 'yes')
{
  echo 'A is checked';
}
else
{
  echo 'Something else is checked.';
}
```

note: make sure your form method is POST.

Comment: Thank you, @train_fox `<form action="checkbox-form.php" method="post">` is my form method, so that should be fine. However, the code is echoing `echo 'Something else is checked.';`. Any Ideas?


Please note: My code to check the checkbox is in a different file, will that affect the outcome?

Comment: Sorry, my if statement was wrong, your value is yes no A. Please try new one.

Comment: I see what you did there. I am not sure why, but it's still displaying the `else` echo. [Picture of Issue](http://grabilla.com/05314-53ef9b90-7134-4a54-b166-ef746ef6230a.html#)

Comment: try var_dump($_POST); before using post variables and see what it contains.

Comment: `array(0) { }` is what was returned for the `else`

Comment: Ok, it seems your post variable is not set at all. Check your code for misspelling some where, perhaps ' or " miss or duplicate.

Comment: I can't seem to find any. Thanks for your help.